# Django 2 - How to run query against multiple non-db field values

Tags: django, django-orm

I am having hard times to find some smart and reliable way how to run multiple annotations per every specified datetime I provide at the start of query, and are not stored in Database because are calculated on-the-fly.

**My data**

```py
from datetime import datetime

business_dates = [
    datetime(year=2016, month=1, day=5),
    datetime(year=2016, month=1, day=6),
    datetime(year=2016, month=1, day=7),
]
```

**My models:**

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Not specified')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Desired output**

Please keep in mind `total_employee_count` should display total count of employees up to mentioned date. Mentioned data may not be so nicely sequential as data example shows.

```py
[
    {'date': datetime(year=2016, month=1, day=5), 'total_employee_count': 22},
    {'date': datetime(year=2016, month=1, day=6), 'total_employee_count': 24},
    {'date': datetime(year=2016, month=1, day=7), 'total_employee_count': 29},
]
```

**What I dont want:**

Loop `business_dates` and run one separate query for each date. In case of 100 dates, I dont want to run 100 separate queries. Lets say, running subqueryies is alright for now.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the models? Employee I guess, etc..

Comment: Information added.

Comment: can you add the DateField too? and the model that is related to Employee?

Comment: Information added.

Comment: Employee has no related models.

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is to group by date and do an aggregate count of employees with that creation date. You don't really need the list of dates for that, but you could filter by creation date >= min(list_of_dates) and creation_date <= max(list_of_dates) and then fill in the missing dates with zeros in a loop.

Comment: Will the days always be nicely sequential like that, without days in between?

Comment: @RishiG No it will not

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db.models import Count, DateTimeField
from django.db.models.functions import Trunc
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


business_dates = [
    datetime.datetime(year=2016, month=1, day=5),
    datetime.datetime(year=2016, month=1, day=6),
    datetime.datetime(year=2016, month=1, day=7),
]


ret = (
    Employee.objects
    .annotate(day=Trunc('created', 'day', output_field=DateTimeField()))
    .filter(day__in=business_dates)
    .values('day')
    .annotate(count=Count('id'))
    .values('day', 'count')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem:

```
from django.db.models import Count
...
Employee.objects.filter(
  created__in=business_dates
).values(
    'created'
).annotate(
    employee_count=Count('pk')
)
```

What we are doing here is grouping by date (while filtering by the list you want) and then counting the amount of objects per date.

Comment: This solution would show exactly number of `employees` joined mentioned dates, not counting employees who joined up to mentioned date. This was caused by non-well explained question. I updated.